# .htaccess - replacing last hyphen (out of many) with a forward slash [regex?]

Tags: regex, .htaccess, regex-lookarounds

I have xxxx's of URLs which are in the following format:

`http://www.example.com/sub/worda-wordb-wordc-123456789`

However I have external links to my site with the URLs in the following format:

```
http://www.example.com/sub/worda-wordb-wordc/123456789
```

I'd like to redirect all URLs from

`http://www.example.com/sub/worda-wordb-wordc/123456789`

to

`http://www.example.com/sub/worda-wordb-wordc-123456789`

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to *redirect* the old one to the new one and then *rewrite* the new one back to the old one? And please show the content of your current `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Oh, and is `sub` dynamic?

Comment: sub is always the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect URI with last slash, replacing with hyphen
RewriteRule ^sub/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ /sub/$1-$2 [R=302,L]
```

Here, we are checking for letters, digits, underscores, and hyphens with `([\w-]+)`, digits with `(\d+)` and an optional slash on the end with `/?`, just to be sure, and then redirecting it accordingly.

Be sure to make this one of your first rules, and then change `302` to `301` to make the redirect cached by browsers and search engines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ /sub/$1-$2
```

Now if you go to `http://www.example.com/sub/worda-wordb-wordc/123456789` the url will be rewritted to `http://www.example.com/sub/worda-wordb-wordc-123456789`.

If this is not what you were looking for please add more details to your question.

Comment: Thanks - It was mean't to rewrite the opposite way round so I have changed it to the following:

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)-([0-9]+)$ /sub/$1/$2

The output is now

http://www.example.com/sub/worda-wordb-wordc-123456789/123456789

Comment: This leaves the original set of numbers in the new URL.

Example:

'http://www.example.com/sub/worda-wordb-wordc-123456789'

Becomes: 'http://www.example.com/sub/worda-wordb-wordc-123456789/123456789/'

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(sub)/(.*)-(\d+)/?$ /$1/$2/$3
```